# Structural Equation Model no solution found

Tags: r, convergence, structural-equation-modeling

I'm trying to use the lavaan package in R for a SEM. I'm using ~30 variables. I scaled the variables with the scale() function. This is how my model looks like:

```
model <- '
  erfahrung_spieler =~ Bulispiele + Bulispiele2 +
                       UEFA_Cup + Profivertrag_Spieler_dummy + 
                       Spiele_Ausland
  erfahrung_trainer =~ A_Spiele_Chef + A_VD_Cheftrainer + A_VD + 
                       A_VD_Verein + A_VD_Chef_Jugend + 
                       A_Trainerstationen + A_VD_Herren_Chef + 
                       A_VD_Co_Herren + A_VD_Co_Profi + 
                       A_VD_Funktionär + A_Titel_Herren + A_Punkte + 
                       SLA_Punkte + A_Pause
  wissen =~  Profidebüt_Jahr + Profidebüt_Alter
  erfolg_debut =~ S1P_VD + S1P_Leistungsklasse_ord
  erfolg_nach_debut =~ P_VD_D + P_Punkte + Titel_Profi

  # regression
  erfolg_debut ~ erfahrung_spieler + erfahrung_trainer +
                 wissen
  erfolg_nach_debut ~ erfahrung_spieler + erfahrung_trainer +
                      wissen + erfolg_debut
'

ergebnis <- sem(model = model, data = scaled_data)

summary(ergebnis)
```

However, this doesn't give me the results I expected, as seen by the summary:

[image]

I don't have much knowledge in this domain, so there might be obvious flaws in the approach. I don't know what else I could do at this point to make it converge due to my limited knowledge of statistics.

Comment: 2 of your latents are measured by only 2 observed variables. While this is technically and theoretically OK it often leads to problems in the final model. Are you able to fit seperate measurement models with no problem ?

Comment: I managed to create a model that converges when I removed the 2 latents and added the observed variables to other latents. Could you explain why this works now?

Comment: There wasn't enough information in the data to provide estimates for the previous model. Your model was empirically unidentified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model is empirically unidentified. This means that there is insufficient information in the data to estimate one or more of the latent variables. This could be simply due to a small sample size or that those latent variables are simply not measured well by the observed variables.

In the model building process it is often a good idea to fit the measurement models first and assess the model fit. A measurement model is a model that contains just latent variables and the observed variables that measure them. Once you have arrived at an adequate measurement model, then add the structural components. Note that in some software you may have to fit a seperate measurement model for each latent variables.